# How can I find a sequence of bytes in a pool of memory?

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way to search for N consecutive bytes within a larger array of bytes.

This is one of my attempts so far.

```
public int FindOffset() {
    byte[] bytesToFind = new byte[] { 0x77, 0x35, 0x94, 0x00 };
    int currentOffset = 0;
    for(;;) {
        byte[] mem = MemoryReader.Read(currentOffset, 4);
        if(bytesToFind == mem || mem == bytesToFind)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Offset.ToString());
            break;
        }
        currentOffset++;
    }
    return currentOffset;
}
```

`MemoryReader.Read` returns an array of bytes.

Comment: I don't see where you Writer is being passed into Read. Is it a global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're almost there. You're comparing the references instead you need to compare the array values. Use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual` and get the job done.

```
for(int Offset =0;Offset<Writer.Length;Offset++)
{
    byte[] mem = Save.Read(Offset, 4);
    if(mem.SequenceEqual(Test))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Offset.ToString());
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Byte array is a reference type. Thus == operator compares pointers not real values. To correct it compare each values: `Test[0] == mem[0] && Test[1] == mem[1] && Test[2] == mem[2] && Test[3] == mem[3]`
2. You should use another algorithm (for example [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm))